# curving and object

Tags: bezier-curves

I am doing the Ice cream tutorial and I'm having trouble with curving the object. I followed the instructions many times and even started from scratch to fix the problem and still nothing. Everything seems fine until I change the curve type to the Bezier curve after making the fit type to fit curve. The end of the ice cream just is extended really far. I tried undoing it and repositioning the draw lines but that only seemed to slightly change it but still same issue.[image: Ice cream disaster]

Comment: Make sure your curve object was created at (and remains at) the Worldspace Origin, as well as your target object (at least until all modifiers are applied, meaning "finalized"). Also, realize that Blender always uses Local Space coordinates, not Global ones, to define the axis of influence for modifiers (these two coordinate spaces are sometimes not in alignment, leading to counterintuitive results). Finally, check and see what other modifiers may be in the modifier stack that could be interfering with the results. If none of this helps, I'd need to see your file. https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: Thank you for your help. I restarted the whole project and got past that part and it has been going pretty smooth so far. I kept moving the objects around and i believe that was the problem because i didn't move anything in the new project thats been work. Im not sure exactly what to look for regarding the coordinates to see if anything is off. I will upload the original project if you wouldn't mind checking and letting me know so I can be aware to avoid these kind of mistakes. Again thank you very much you are a great help to new people like myself. :)

Comment: When I say the coordinate spaces are not always in alignment, I mean the local X, Y, and Z of an object doesn't always coincide with the global X, Y and Z of the world. We tend to think in global space when performing operations, and when objects are first created, the local and global space coordinates are indeed aligned (Local X to Global X, Local Y to Global Y, etc.). But in the course of working, it can be that the local coordinates no longer align (Local X to Global Y, etc.). If you created a modifier to influence global Y, yet unknowingly target local x, you won't understand the results.